# Selecting records between two dates

Tags: mysql, date

I have the following query:

```
SELECT dm.app_id, apt.app_name, COUNT(dm.app_id) 
FROM dm_openapp dm
JOIN app_table apt ON dm.app_id = apt.app_id
GROUP BY dm.app_id
```

Basically this table also has dates associated to each record, and I need to get a range of all the records between time X and Y, I tried using the following, for example, but to no avail:

```
WHERE dm.dl_time BETWEEN '2011-05-31' AND '2011-05-06'
```

Any idea as to what to do? the dl_time column is a timestamp type.

Comment: So instead of the string '2011-05-31' use the timestamp that corresponds to that date. On the other hand, you could convert timestamp field to datetime, as you should never store dates in timestamp format (timestamp and datetime are both internally handled as integers meaning 4 bytes each, so it's pointless to go for timestamp when datetime offers so much more when it comes to dates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ummm... you've got the data the wrong way around. `BETWEEN` must be LOW value to HIGH value:

Try this:

```
WHERE dm.dl_time BETWEEN '2011-05-06' AND '2011-05-31' -- Note date values swapped
```

You can ignore the other answers, which also haven't noticed this...

Comment: +1 good spotting. Since `dl_time` is timestamp and the two (start and end) dates are dates, I would also write the condition as: `WHERE '2011-05-06' <= dm.dl_time AND dm.dl_time < '2011-06-01'`

Answer (score 7):

It is better to use DATETIME column type for these things. Than this should work: use [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. Also, swap the BETWEEN values.

```
WHERE dm.dl_time BETWEEN str_to_date('2011-05-06','%Y-%m-%d') AND str_to_date('2011-05-31','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date_column
FROM dates
WHERE date(date_column)<='2011-05-06' AND date(date_column)>='2011-05-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings in your where clause to a date `STR_TO_DATE`.  Here are a variety of different functions in MySQL that you can use for DATE manipulation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html