# PHP SQL Select between 4 columns

Tags: sql

I´m looking for a solution, where I can select the entries between 2 dates. My table is like this

```
ID | YEAR | MONTH | ....
```

Now i want to SELECT all entries between

```
MONTH 9 | YEAR 2015
MONTH 1 | YEAR 2016
```

I don´t get any entries, because the 2nd month is lower than the 1st month. Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YEAR >= '$year' 
AND MONTH >= '$month' 
AND YEAR <= '$year2' 
AND MONTH <= '$month2'
```

I can´t change the columns of the table, because a csv import is like this. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: maybe you will find an answer her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329830/selecting-records-between-two-dates

Comment: swidmann: No, his structure is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The years aren't disconnected from the months, so you can't test them separately.

Try something like

```
$date1 = $year*100+$month;   // will be 201509
$date2 = $year2*100+$month2; // will be 201602
...
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (YEAR*100)+MONTH >= '$date1' AND (YEAR*100)+MONTH <= '$date2'
```

Make sure you protect against SQL injection though.

Comment: You're assuming that the month variable is zero padded in both the php-variable and the database. Otherwise it will show the wrong values if date1 is 201510 and date2 is 20162

Comment: @MagnusEriksson He's creating the PHP variables using arithmetic, not concatenation. `201600 + 2` will be `201602`, not `20162`.

Comment: I'd add some tick marks around YEAR and MONTH since those are reserved function names in MySQL. You probably shouldn't name your columns MONTH and YEAR either.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `my_table`
WHERE
    ((`YEAR` * 12) + `MONTH`) >= (($year * 12) + $month)
    AND ((`YEAR` * 12) + `MONTH`) <= (($year2 * 12) + $month2)
```

Since they aren't date fields, you need to convert to numbers that can be compared against. Multiplying the year by 12 and adding the month will give you a unique number specific to that month of the year. Then you can compare on that.

Comment: Hi - It's useful for others if you add an explanation of your code

Comment: I'm new here. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of good answers, but assuming taht you don't/can't change the date's format something you can do is

```
WHERE ((YEAR>'$year') OR
       (YEAR=='$year' AND MONTH>='$month')
AND ((YEAR<'$year2') OR
       (YEAR=='$year2' AND MONTH<='$month2')
```

I would suggest the workarounds though (like alphabetically comparing in YYYYMM[DD] format).

Answer (score 0):

Though there are a lot of ways to solve this problem, but the best way is to convert these values into a proper date type in mysql query using `str_to_date` it is PHP's equivalent of `strtotime`, your new query should look like this

```
SELECT 
    d.* 
from 
    dates as d 
where 
    STR_TO_DATE( concat('1,',d.month,',',d.year) ,'%d,%m,%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('1,5,2015','%d,%m,%Y')
and
    STR_TO_DATE( concat('1,',d.month,',',d.year) ,'%d,%m,%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('1,4,2016','%d,%m,%Y')
```

Using this technique you can easily compare dates and do much more and not worry about other complexities of calendars.

Source: [MySQL date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pad the month to make sure it starts with a zero. Otherwise 20162 will be lower than 201512, for example.

```
$date1 = $year . str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$date2 = $year2 . str_pad($month2, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

"SELECT * FROM dates WHERE concat(`year`, LPAD(`month`, 2, '0')) >= '$date1' AND concat(`year`, LPAD(`month`, 2, '0')) <= '$date2'"
```