# between two dates result will be wrong

Tags: mysql

I have a table and have a column name as dates, **data type is varchar(50).**
like this:

```
dates
-------
16/06/2017
25/05/2017
03/06/2017
17/06/2017
03/06/2017
12/06/2017
05/06/2017
06/06/2017
15/06/2017
13/06/2017
29/04/2017
21/05/2017
```

I tried this:

```
select s.date 
from add_vehicle a 
left join services s 
    ON a.vid=s.vid 
where date BETWEEN '01/04/2017' AND '19/06/2017'
```

**I only get 6th month data only.**

If I change the '19/06/2017' to '30/06/2017' then I get balance results.

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Guide me please.

*Note:sqlfiddle not working*

Comment: Dont store Dates as varchar. Always store it in a date Format. In the meantime you have to convert the string into date. Read the mysql documentation how you can do it

Comment: Change your column data type to DATE

Comment: i know that but what should i do if i am using varchar means

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting records between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329830/selecting-records-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your data!  Databases support date/time data types for a reason.  That is because you should use them.  In your case, you can do:

```
UPDATE t
SET dates = date_format(str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Then, alter the data type:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY dates date;
```

Voila!  Your code will start working.

Don't write overly complicated queries to get around a problem in the data. Fix the data.